# How do I retrieve data from Conditions

Tags: magento2, php, widget, data, condition

I have a problem. I created a widget where inside `<parameters>` I have a field with `conditions`.

```xml
<parameter name="products" xsi:type="conditions" visible="true" required="true" sort_order="1"
           class="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\Widget\Conditions">
    <label translate="true">Products</label>
</parameter>
```

I also have other fields in there and I pull them out using `$block->getData('name of data');`. And this is where the problem arises. In this conditions I set if `is one of` and I want to pull it in phtml using `$block->getData('products')` then I get this error `main.CRITICAL: Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null`.

I expected to get an array with values indicated inside this conditions e.g. there are 6 products selected by SKU. And I wanted to get an array of these SKUs. How to do it? Help please.

[image]